# Allure manual configuration on MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, allure

Since brew install allure is giving us error and they are trying to fix it.
[can check it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080764/allure-2-0-homebrew-install-issue)

Meanwhile can you please let me know the process to install allure on mac manually.

I am setting it up for the first time on MAC OS X. Hence need to know how to set the System path for allure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it setup

1. download the .zip file and extract it
2. go to the terminal and open the .bash_profile "open -e .bash.profile"
3. add the export PATH="path to the bin folder:$PATH" and save the file
4. quit the terminal. open it again and try allure --version

Comment: You can download Allure from Github releases: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip